# fcntl(), F_GETFD meaning in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, file-descriptor

What is the meaning of F_GETFD in fcntl() function in unix ?, From what I understand it should return -1 if there is no file descriptor in the position specified.. If that's true, when would it happen ? when doing close to a file descriptor in that posstion, F_GETFD doesn't return -1 either..

This is a part of a program using F_GETFD and it will not return -1 if I close the x fd (thid fd entered 0 in the fd table since we closed 0 beforehand and did dup(x)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>


void try(){
printf("got_sig\n");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int x, stdout=1;
signal(SIGUSR1,&try);
x = open("t1.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
close(0);
dup(x);
close(x);
if (fcntl(0,F_GETFD)==-1)
printf("false\n");
kill(getpid(),SIGUSR1);
//close(x);
write(stdout,"BYE\n",4);
exit(0);
}
```

When will F_GETFD return -1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page of fcntl()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html):

> **File descriptor flags**
>          The  following  commands manipulate the flags associated with a file descriptor.  Currently, only one such flag is defined: FD_CLOEXEC, the close-on-exec flag.  If the FD_CLOEXEC bit
>          is set, the file descriptor will automatically be closed during a successful execve(2).
>
> F_GETFD (void)
>                 Return (as the function result) the file descriptor flags; arg
>                 is ignored.

<sub>(Or see the [POSIX standard text for fctnl()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fcntl.html), if you care.)</sub>

So, `fnctl(fd, F_GETFD)` tells you if the file descriptor stays open over an `execve()` or not.

The usual error cases for `fcntl()` apply, so it would e.g. return -1 and set `errno` to `EBADF` if the fd you gave wasn't open. In your code, you called `fcntl()` on fd 0, which holds the dup'ed copy of `x`, and so is open. `fcntl()` would return -1 for the fd `x`, though, that's the one you explicitly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the implementation of [do_fcntl](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/fcntl.c#L337) in the Linux kernel, we can see that:

```
static long do_fcntl(int fd, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg,
        struct file *filp)
{
    long err = -EINVAL;
    switch (cmd) {
    ...
    case F_GETFD:
        err = get_close_on_exec(fd) ? FD_CLOEXEC : 0;
        break;
    ...
    }
    return err;
}
```

`do_fcntl(F_GETFD)` may return only `FD_CLOEXEC` or 0.

The syscall definition from [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/fcntl.c#L450) can return `-EBADF` in case of a bad file descriptor or the file descriptor was opened with `O_PATH`.

Judging from that, the `fcntl(F_GETFD)` will return only -1 with errno set to -9 (`-EBADF`), or return 0 or 1 (`FD_CLOEXEC`) on Linux 4.20. So the `fcntl(F_GETFD)` will return `-1` in case of a bad file descriptor or file descriptor opened with `O_PATH`. Note that for other kernels it may be different and note that it can change over time.